# Geometry - sphere related question

Tags: geometry

Eight spheres of radius 1 one per octant are each tangent to the coordinate planes. What is the radius of the small sphere centred at the origin that contains these eight spheres ?

Following are the options :

(a) $\sqrt2$

(b) $\sqrt 3$

(c) $1 +\sqrt2$

(d) $1+ \sqrt3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  draw the diagonal from $(1,1,1)$ to $(-1,-1,-1)$.  The small sphere is tangent to two of the unit spheres where this diagonal hits them.  This means the diameter is from one intersection to the other.